# Using an INSERT query that one column came from another table

Tags: sql-server

With these tables:

**Table1**

```
Date | Barcode | Sold | AmountSold
```

**Table2**

```
Barcode | Description | RetailPrice
 00001       Item1         1.00
 00002       Item2         2.00
 00003       Item3         3.00
 00004       Item4         4.00
 00005       Item5         5.00
```

Is there a way to use an `INSERT` to `Table1`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
VALUES ('07/11/2017', '00003', 5, (? * 5))
```

With the `?` being the `RetailPrice` *(which is `3.00`)* of `00003` from `Table2`, then multiplied with `Sold` *(which is `5`)*?

I have stumbled upon [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp), but this requires that all column that will be inserted will have a matching value from `SELECT`, which I do not need.

***Note:*** the first three values will come from an external source, so the 4th value will be the only one that need to come from another table

I can of course use another query first to get the `RetailPrice` before inserting, but I'm avoiding to use this way to reduce loading time.

Comment: You could load the data from the external source into a `physical/temp/variable table` and then use `insert into select` with a `from clause` which would contain a `join` between the newly introduced table (that has the first 3 columns) and table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1
    VALUES ('07/11/2017', '00003', 5, ((SELECT RetailPrice
                                               FROM dbo.table2
                                               WHERE dbo.table2.Barcode = '00003') * 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are after something like this one:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (Date, Barcode , Sold , AmountSold)
SELECT '07/11/2017', '00003', 5, 5 * RetailPrice
FROM Table2
-- WHERE Barcode = 'XXX'
```

Comment: So that means that the first three value from `SELECT` can be anything even with `FROM Table2`?

Comment: This is a mixture of needs I have to say :) Do achieve that you have to specify your values in WHERE clause to include / exclude barcodes you want to insert or you don't.

Comment: @BartoszX the first three columns are also coming from a set of data, not fixed strings.